# Python set more properties with 1 call

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I have a very expensive method that returns 2 values, and it is called by class `A`. Since it is expensive, I made the 2 values lazy evaluated, using properties. Since I don't want to call the `very_expensive_function` 2 times, the first time the user wants to access one of the 2 values, I save both.

So far I wrote this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._attr1 = None
        self._attr2 = None

    @property
    def attr1(self):
        self.calculate_metrics()
        return self._attr1


    @property
    def attr2(self):
        self.calculate_metrics()
        return self._attr2

    def calculate_metrics():
        if self._attr1 is None:
            attr1, attr2 = very_expensive_call()
            self._attr1 = attr1
            self._attr2 = attr2
```

As you can see, the first time the user access to `attr1` or `attr2`, I save both. Is it correct or is it possible in another way? It seems very strange to have that `calculate_metrics()` copy-pasted every time.

Comment: As far as Im aware this is the way to do it.

Comment: Are there any parameters passed to `very_expensive_call`? If there are you may be able to use memoization.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes there are parameters, what do you mean by "I can use memorisation"?

Comment: I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Memoization is, simply put, remembering if you have already called a function with particular arguments. If you have it simply returns the already calculated return value rather than calculating it again.

```
import time
def long_calculation(x, y, memo={}):
    try:
        result = memo[x, y] # already calculated!
    except KeyError:
        # make long_calculation take a long time!
        time.sleep(2)
        result = x * y
        memo[x, y] = result
    return result
```

The dictionary `memo` is able to  remember calls to the function because it is evaluated when the function is first loaded: every call to `long_calculation` shares the same `memo` dictionary.

To test this try:

```
# Note that (2,2) (7,8) and (10,10) are repeated here:
test_values = ((2,2),(4,5),(2,2),(7,8),(2,3),(7,8),(10,11),(4,5),(10,10),(10,10))

for values in test_values:
    start = time.time()
    res = long_calculation(*values)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end-start
    print(values,' calculated in ',elapsed, "seconds")
```

It should be fairly easy to insert this kind of code into your class. If you always need the attributes calculated then you can put the call in `__init__`.